# Adding Horizontal And Vertical Responsive Padding Inside a Div Using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have some trouble with a horizontal and vertical text-align and responsive design:

the situation:

- I use Bootstrap
- The row is separated in two columns of the same size (col-sm-6 / 50%)
- For the left Column, I want to apply a Background-Image
- For the right Column, I want to add a text (description to the picture)
- To keep the dimensions of both Columns the same I added to both Columns a
  Background-Image of the same size

the problem:

- left and right Column should always have the same Dimension
- Text should be always centred horizontally and vertically in its column

more informations :

- I tried a couple of solutions, like adding padding to the top (changes position, when changing screen size) and using transform:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.header_ueber_uns_text {
            color: white;
              width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            padding-left: 4%;
        }
        
        .header_ueber_uns_background_image {
           padding-bottom: 30.1%;
        height: 0;
        background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1700x645');
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        
        .ueber_uns_image_box_1 {
                   padding-bottom: 38%;
        height: 0;
        background-image: url('http://placehold.it/800x600');
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;  
        }

        .ueber_uns_image_box_2 {
                   padding-bottom: 38%;
        height: 0;
        background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1867/9985/files/backgrundi.jpg?6191691157048477587');
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;  
        }
        
        .ueber_uns_text {
       color: grey;
        text-align: center;
            padding-left: 50px;
            padding-right: 50px;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 header_ueber_uns_background_image ">
            <div class="header_ueber_uns_text">
            <h6>ÜBER UNS</h6>
            <h3>KREATIVES DESIGN AUS BERLIN</h3>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ueber_uns_image_box_1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 ueber_uns_image_box_2">
            <div class="ueber_uns_text">
            <img src="Images/werkzeug_moebel_freund_manufaktur-300x243.png" width="100px" alt="">
            <h6>ÜBER UNS</h6>
            <p>Seit Jahren designen und bauen wir für unseren Bekanntenkreis. Nach dem Studium gaben wir unserer Leidenschaft Raum. Wir widmeten uns ganz einem Material (Kupfer) und einem Möbelstück (dem Hocker). Freunde lichteten unsere Debutserie ab und öffneten uns damit die Türen zu renommierten Design-Adressen. Inzwischen sind wir zu dritt, haben ein Atelier in Weißensee und arbeiten dort auch mit vielen anderen Kreativen und Künstlern zusammen.</p>
            </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ueber_uns_image_box_2">
            <div class="ueber_uns_text">
            <h6>ÜBER UNS</h6>
            <p>Seit Jahren designen und bauen wir für unseren Bekanntenkreis. Nach dem Studium gaben wir unserer Leidenschaft Raum. Wir widmeten uns ganz einem Material (Kupfer) und einem Möbelstück (dem Hocker). Freunde lichteten unsere Debutserie ab und öffneten uns damit die Türen zu renommierten Design-Adressen. Inzwischen sind wir zu dritt, haben ein Atelier in Weißensee und arbeiten dort auch mit vielen anderen Kreativen und Künstlern zusammen.</p>
            </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-sm-6 ueber_uns_image_box_1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an img tag inside the first column to display the image like this instead of adding it as a background image:

```
<div class="col-sm-6"><img src="your-image-url-here" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center;line-height:[height-of-your-image-here];"><p style="vertical-align: middle;">Your text here</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.header_ueber_uns_text {
            color: white;
              width: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            padding-left: 4%;
        }
        
        .header_ueber_uns_background_image {
           padding-bottom: 30.1%;
        height: 0;
        background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1700x645');
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        
        .ueber_uns_image_box_1 {
                   padding-bottom: 38%;
        height: 0;
        background-image: url('http://placehold.it/800x600');
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;  
        }

        .ueber_uns_image_box_2 {
                   padding-bottom: 38%;
        height: 0;
        background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1867/9985/files/backgrundi.jpg?6191691157048477587');
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;  
        }
        
        .ueber_uns_text {
       color: grey;
        text-align: center;
            padding-left: 50px;
            padding-right: 50px;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 header_ueber_uns_background_image ">
            <div class="header_ueber_uns_text">
            <h6>ÜBER UNS</h6>
            <h3>KREATIVES DESIGN AUS BERLIN</h3>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ueber_uns_image_box_1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 ueber_uns_image_box_2">
            <div class="ueber_uns_text">
            <img src="Images/werkzeug_moebel_freund_manufaktur-300x243.png" width="100px" alt="">
            <h6>ÜBER UNS</h6>
            <p>Seit Jahren designen und bauen wir für unseren Bekanntenkreis. Nach dem Studium gaben wir unserer Leidenschaft Raum. Wir widmeten uns ganz einem Material (Kupfer) und einem Möbelstück (dem Hocker). Freunde lichteten unsere Debutserie ab und öffneten uns damit die Türen zu renommierten Design-Adressen. Inzwischen sind wir zu dritt, haben ein Atelier in Weißensee und arbeiten dort auch mit vielen anderen Kreativen und Künstlern zusammen.</p>
            </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ueber_uns_image_box_2">
            <div class="ueber_uns_text">
            <h6>ÜBER UNS</h6>
            <p>Seit Jahren designen und bauen wir für unseren Bekanntenkreis. Nach dem Studium gaben wir unserer Leidenschaft Raum. Wir widmeten uns ganz einem Material (Kupfer) und einem Möbelstück (dem Hocker). Freunde lichteten unsere Debutserie ab und öffneten uns damit die Türen zu renommierten Design-Adressen. Inzwischen sind wir zu dritt, haben ein Atelier in Weißensee und arbeiten dort auch mit vielen anderen Kreativen und Künstlern zusammen.</p>
            </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-sm-6 ueber_uns_image_box_1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```